# Did I use parameters correctly?

Tags: java, parameters

So I'm a beginner which you can probably tell and I am currently trying to understand parameters and was wondering if I did this correctly. The program works but I didn't want to have it formatted wrong or maybe I used them for no reason since the arguments(?) don't change. We are currently studying parameters so I figured I'd give it a shot and try to include it in this assignment.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Investments
    {
        public static void main(String []args)
    {

        double investment,interestRate, futureValue;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is the investment amount?");
        investment = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What is the interest rate?");
        interestRate=keyboard.nextDouble();

        futureValue = investment * (Math.pow(1+interestRate, 5));
        futureValue = investments(futureValue);
        System.out.println("Your investment afer 5 years:" + futureValue);

        futureValue = investment * (Math.pow(1+interestRate, 10));
        futureValue = investments(futureValue);
        System.out.println("Your investment after 10 years:" + futureValue);

        futureValue = investment * (Math.pow(1+interestRate, 20));
        futureValue = investments(futureValue);
        System.out.println("Your investment after 20 years:" + futureValue);

    }

    public static double investments (double futureValue)
    {
        double result;

        result = Math.round(futureValue * 100);
        result = result/100;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running it, thats the best way to check, if your code works :-)? Seems ok to me.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the feedback. I did run it and it works! I just needed to know if I did it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks pretty good! If you want to make your investments function even more powerful you can move all the logic into there, and just pass in the investment, interest rate and investment period.

```
public static double investments (double investment, double interestRate, int numYears)
```

Then your main function can just be:

```
futureValue = investments(interestRate, 5); 
System.out.println("Your investment after 5 years:" + futureValue);

futureValue = investments(interestRate, 10); 
System.out.println("Your investment after 10 years:" + futureValue);
```

(etc)